# FileAllowed does not display an error message

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am using WTForms. I am applying validation on file upload  and restricted it to jpg,png and pdf format only. however if i give an incorrect input, no error message appears.

I followed this tutorial
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html

```py
photo = FileField('photo', validators=[
        FileRequired(),
        FileAllowed(['png', 'pdf', 'jpg'], "wrong format!")
    ])
```

Comment: Are you checking for `form.validate_on_submit ()` ?

Comment: read this document https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/crash_course.html#displaying-errors

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, `flask-wtf` does not show any error message if validation fails.

Error messages can be caught and shown for each individual field or for all fields together.

Here is an example of file upload with validation in `flask-wtf`.

Folder structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── forms.py
├── requirements.txt
└── templates
    └── upload.html
```

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import FileUploadForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'learnflask'

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    form = FileUploadForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        f = form.photo_or_pdf_file.data
        return f.filename
    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

`forms.py`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed, FileRequired


class FileUploadForm(FlaskForm):
    photo_or_pdf_file = FileField('photo', validators=[
        FileRequired(),
        FileAllowed(['png', 'pdf', 'jpg'], "wrong format!")
    ])
    submit = SubmitField('Upload')
```

`templates/upload.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>login</title>
    <style>
        .validation_error{
        color: red;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.photo_or_pdf_file.label }}<br>{{ form.photo_or_pdf_file }}
    <span class="validation_error">{{ ', '.join(form.photo_or_pdf_file.errors) }}</span><br>
    {{ form.submit }}<br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

- For invalid file format (audio file):

[image]

- For valid file format (.png format)

[image: valid upload]

`requirements.txt`:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
Werkzeug==0.15.4
WTForms==2.2.1
```

Running the application:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

**Reference:**

- [Displaying errors in WTF](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/crash_course.html#displaying-errors)
- [File uploads using flask-wtf](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form.html#module-flask_wtf.file)

Comment: Kindly asking, how can I display the error as a flash error?

Comment: I do not think that we can use message flashing directly for WTF validation errors. Can you try adding an else in `.validate_on_submit()` and check if you flash the `form.photo_or_pdf_file.errors`?