# Flask FileAllowed validator not detecting errors - How to write a custom validator?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have the same issue as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56225591/fileallowed-does-not-display-an-error-message), but the listed solutions do not solve the problem.

I am creating a blog website using Flask, and on the user account page (route shown below)

---

**routes.py imports**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from pgblog.models import User
from flask_login import current_user
```

**routes.py - account route**

```
@app.route("/account", methods=["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def account():
    form = UpdateAccountForm()
    
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.username=form.username.data
        current_user.email=form.email.data
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your Account has been Updated.", "success")
        return redirect(url_for("account"))

    elif request.method == "GET":
        form.username.data = current_user.username
        form.email.data = current_user.email

    image_file = url_for("static", filename="profile_pics/" + current_user.image_file)
    return render_template("account.html", title="Account", image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

---

users are able to change their profile image. The form to update account information is shown below:

---

**forms.py imports**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileAllowed
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo, ValidationError
from pgblog.models import User
from flask_login import current_user
```

**forms.py - UpdateAccountForm**

```
class UpdateAccountForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("Username", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3,max=20)])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    picture = FileField("Update Profile Picture", validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'], "wrong format!")])

    submit = SubmitField("Update")

    def validate_picture(self, picture):
        if picture.errors:
            raise ValidationError("Images only!")


    def validate_username(self, username):
        if username.data != current_user.username:
            if User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first():
                raise ValidationError("That username is taken. Please choose a different one.")
    
    def validate_email(self, email):
        if email.data != current_user.email:
            if User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first():
                raise ValidationError("That email is taken. Please choose a different one.")
```

---

And the errors are meant to be displayed in the following div:

---

**account.html - picture upload div**

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form.picture.label(class="form-control-label") }}
    {{ form.picture() }}

    {% if form.picture.errors %}
        <ul class="invalid-feedback">{% for error in form.picture.errors %}<li>{{ error }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

form.hidden.tag() is included in account.html as well as form.submit()

However, regardless of filetype, I can't get an error to appear!

Am I doing something wrong? Or, alternatively, is there a way that I can write my own validation function?

EDIT:
I misspelled enctype="multipart/form-data">!!! Everything is working, thanks for clicking!

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, and it works fine with uploading user profile pictures

```
@app.route("/updateaccount", methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
    @login_required 
    def updateaccount():
        form = UpdateAccountForm() 
        if form.validate_on_submit(): 
            if form.picture.data:
                picture_file = save_picture(form.picture.data)
                current_user.image_file = picture_file
            current_user.username = form.username.data 
            current_user.email = form.email.data 
            db.session.commit() 
            flash('Your account has been updated!', 'success') 
            return redirect(url_for('updateaccount')) 
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            form.username.data = current_user.username 
            form.email.data = current_user.email 
        image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + current_user.image_file)
        return render_template('account.html', title='Account',image_file=image_file, form=form)
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply! Ultimately, the error was a typo within my HTML. I misspelled multipart iirc.

Comment: Do you save the picture-file in a directory or in database?

Comment: I saved in database